# How to hide div that is referenced by an anchor href on click with javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several blocks of text separated into their own divs. I also have several links in a navigation bar that reference these divs with an anchor link. On click, I'd like to hide all other divs except the one referenced by the clicked link. I have:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#section1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section3">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section4">Link 4</a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, when I click 'Link 3'. I'd like to hide all divs except #section3.

I'm fine actually hiding/showing each section of text using CSS, but I can't figure out how to use the link's href attribute to reference the div name.

Thanks for your help, and let me know if you need clarification of what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the anchor's [`.hash` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement) as a selector, all you need to so is hide the divs you want first, like this:

```
$('#navbar a').click(function(e) {
    $('.container > div').hide();
    $(this.hash).show();
    e.preventDefault(); //to prevent scrolling
});
```

This assumes you have the `<div>` elements you want to show in a container of some sort, like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="section1">Section 1</div>
  <div id="section2">Section 2</div>
  <div id="section3">Section 3</div>
  <div id="section4">Section 4</div>
</div>
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3G8tH/).

Comment: Wow - great. This is exactly the functionality I was looking for. I didn't know that I could use `.hash` as a selector - perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @tsrich - yup, since it's identical to an ID selector it's pretty handy *and* cheaper, win-win :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#navbar a').click(function() {
    $('div:not(#navbar)').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    return false; // You may or may not want this line.
});
```

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C27Vz/).